# Debugging javascript code for generating images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, xhtml

Hey guys so I need help figuring out what the error in my javascript code is.

I know exactly where the code stops working, but I can't figure out what the issue is. Can anyone help?

```
function createCardio(){
var randomimages=new Array();

randomimages[0]="images/strength/armcircles.gif";
randomimages[1]="images/strength/calfraises.gif";
/**add more images**/

var preload=new Array()

for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++){
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
}

if(document.getElementById("impact").checked == false && document.getElementById("pregnant").checked == false && document.getElementById("none").checked == false){
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*All fields are required";
}
else if(document.getElementById("beginner").checked == false && document.getElementById("intermediate").checked == false && document.getElementById("advanced").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*All fields are required";
}
else if(document.getElementById("hiit").checked == false && document.getELementById("tabata").checked == false && document.getElementById("circuit").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*All fields are required";
}
else if(document.getElementById("treadmill").checked == false && document.getElementById("bike").checked == false && document.getElementById("jump").checked == false && document.getElementById("equipment").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*All fields are required";
}
else{
if(document.getElementById("equipment").checked == true){
    if(document.getElementById("hiit").checked == true){        
        if(document.getElementById("impact").checked == true && document.getElementById("pregnant").checked == true){
            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Perform each exercise for 40 seconds, followed by 20 seconds of rest (10 min)";

            document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';     
        }

        else if(document.getElementById("impact") == true){
            if(document.getElementById("beginner").checked == true){
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Perform each exercise for 40 seconds, followed by 20 seconds of rest (10 min)";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[43]+'" width=40% height=40%>';   
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Perform each exercise for 40 seconds, followed by 20 seconds of rest (10 min)";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
            }
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("pregnant") == true){
            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Perform each exercise for 40 seconds, followed by 20 seconds of rest (10 min)";

            document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
            document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Perform each exercise for 40 seconds, followed by 20 seconds of rest (10 min)";

            document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
            document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
        }
    }
```

This is where the code stops working

```
else if(document.getElementById("tabata").checked == true){     
            if(document.getElementById("impact").checked == true && document.getElementById("pregnant").checked == true){
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Perform each exercise for 20 seconds, followed by 10 seconds of rest (10 min)Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';     

            }
            else if(document.getElementById("impact") == true){
                if(document.getElementById("beginner").checked == true){
                    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                    document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[43]+'" width=40% height=40%>';   
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                    document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
                }
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("pregnant") == true){
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
            }
        }
        else{
            if(document.getElementById("impact").checked == true && document.getElementById("pregnant").checked == true){
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';     

            }
            else if(document.getElementById("impact") == true){
                if(document.getElementById("beginner").checked == true){
                    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                    document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*36)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[43]+'" width=40% height=40%>';   
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                    document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                    document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*44)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
                }
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("pregnant") == true){
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(52-43)+43)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*15)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("perform").innerHTML = "Complete 3 rounds of 15-20 reps for each move";

                document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img2").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img3").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img4").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img5").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img7").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img8").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img9").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>'; 
                document.getElementById("img10").innerHTML = '<img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*56)]+'" width=40% height=40%>';
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: where can I forget that I see this?

Comment: _"stops working"_ how does it stop working? are you getting errors, is the code doing something weird?

Answer (score 2):

> I need help figuring out what the error in my javascript code is.

Answer: Use the "error console" in your browser to see what the error is. In many browsers, you can get to it by pressing F12.

Answer (score 2):

here

```
else if(document.getElementById("impact") == true){
```

and here

```
else if(document.getElementById("pregnant") == true){
```

you have the .checked attribute in other statements. i'm assuming this is just a typo? :)

there might still be other errors. this is just what stands out to me.
you'll really be better off with the other guy's suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

H i, a few debug tips -

**1) Can shorthand much of this by creating yourself a function like -**

`function _el(str) { return document.getElementById(str); }`

then you can just use `el('img7').innerHTML="...`  to cut down on all those *`document.getElementById`* statements.

**2) Checking if `checked === true` is pointless can just do -**

`if(document.getElementById("impact").checked) { ...`

**3) To debug , use the developer tools in the browser and use/view the `console` like:**

`console.log(document.getElementById("impact").checked)`

Using `console` before lines where you see the code breaking will tell you if elements you are trying to access are found eg.

if `console.log(document.getElementById('perform')` logs as `undefined` you will know that the code will fail to run the next line - `document.getElementById('perform').innerHTML='...`